# Italy entry information - Lost permit in Italy but I have renewal receipt

Tags: italy, denial-of-entry, pakistan, permesso-di-soggiorno, residence-permits

I lost my permit in Italy, applied for it again but since it was expiring they had me apply for a renwal.

I traveled to my home country with a valid visa still but now I want to come back, I only have my receipt of permit renewal and Denucia (Police complaint report in Italy) + Previous copy of lost permit of residence. Will i be allowed back?

Comment: Do you have a passport with a valid Schengen visa (and no overstay on the record)?

Comment: Usually the receipt serves as proof that let's you enter the schengen area. Your best bet is contacting the Italian representation near you and seeing what they say